# Restart Corrupted Workflow Programmatically

Tags: workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation

Recently I encountered this issue wherein inside my log table, my correlation id is currently running but in my AppFabric Persistence Store, that same correlation id has stopped.

I'm thinking of "restarting or rehydrating" that "corrupted" workflow programmatically, but I don't know how? Any tips on how to do this? I'm quite new in this technology.

Thanks!